# Gmail API : Extract "code" param from the URL of a pop-up window to get the access_token details

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-api

Iam trying to authenticate gmail using OAuth2 for my web application. From the server, we return a url to the client, which then uses that to open a pop-up. The code is as shown:

```
        var win = window.open(data.google_oauth_url, `<h1>Gmail</h1>`, 'width=800, height=600');
          var pollTimer = setInterval(() => { 
              try {
                  const searchParams = new URL(win.document.URL).searchParams
                  console.log("url is",win.document.URL, searchParams, searchParams.get("code"))
                  if (searchParams.get("code") != -1) {
                      clearInterval(pollTimer);
                      win.close();
                  }
              } catch(e) {
                console.log("Error",e)
              }
          }, 500);
```

From the pop-up , i want to extract the "code" param which google returns to us after the authentication is completed. But when i try to extract the param from the client side, iam facing an error :

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xyz" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Is anyone aware of a solution for this, or any other ways of extracting the "code" param so i can proceed to get the access_token details.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the node js sample is no help? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: @DaImTo The implementation mode is such that, i return a url from server, at the client side, we are window.open(url), and then I am trying to find a way to get that code param, so that i can send that code param to server to handle the rest.

Comment: Im not really the best person to talk to about JavaScript.  But in my experience mixing server sided and client slide login will only bring you grief.  Pick one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works, although we face CORS error while authenticating with google, once the authentication is complete, it is redirected to the provided url (web application). And then there is no more cross-origin since the domains are now same.

Ex: https://localhost was your web app url, and the redirect url.

Then it detects the authentication code and once obtained, the pop up closes automatically.