# Gmail Oauth2: Capture a request at the browser level after authentication completes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-api

After my web application completes the OAuth process and redirects to my web application only, google returns a "code" in a request to get the access_tokens later. Is there anyway i can capture that request and extract the "code" param from the request ??

Any help would suffice. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail API : Extract "code" param from the URL of a pop-up window to get the access\_token details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647979/gmail-api-extract-code-param-from-the-url-of-a-pop-up-window-to-get-the-acce)

Comment: It seems like a duplicate question of your other thread.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo That question differs in approach. Here i want to know if i can capture a request made in network tab, so that once that request is captured, i can perform the actions later.